# Load testing vuser in Load runner11

Tags: loadrunner

I am using Load runner 11.0. Is it possible to use 1 script with one user id and password to load test 500 vusers with unique Password and user id's in the controller? Or do I have to use a parameter in the Vugen script by sending 500 user id's and Passwords? 
 A detailed answer will be very helpful. i need the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.   Please review your student training documentation on VUGEN parameterization regarding the use of unique data for each user.   As an alternative you can also find this information in the PDF versions of the user manuals which are installed with every copy of LoadRunner under the parameterization section.